# SQLAlchemy DatabaseError server close connection

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am running a several processes in python using multiprocessing. I am hitting a postgresql database and I keep getting this error:

(DatabaseError) server closed the connection unexpectedlyThis probably means the server terminated abnormallybefore or while processing the request.

The db admin tells he is not seeing any errors on his side and I can't figure out what is causings this.